# Ubuntu machine hang and whole LAN network stopped responding

Tags: 14.04, networking, responsiveness

I am getting problems when my Ubuntu machine, it hangs(keyboard,mouse stopped responding, and screen looking blur). Also, the whole lan/wan network stopped responding. Please advise?

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"
```

**Logs from /var/log/syslog file:**

```
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008034] ------------[ cut here ]------------

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008047] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1614 at /build/linux-Y0uW00/linux-3.19.0/net/sched/sch_generic.c:303 dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210()

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008050] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1 (forcedeth): transmit queue 0 timed out

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008052] Modules linked in: cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nouveau snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep mxm_wmi snd_pcm wmi video snd_seq_midi ttm snd_seq_midi_event drm_kms_helper drm snd_rawmidi snd_seq edac_core i2c_algo_bit snd_seq_device edac_mce_amd snd_timer k8temp serio_raw snd soundcore shpchp 8250_fintek i2c_nforce2 tpm_infineon mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 pata_acpi hid_generic usbhid hid forcedeth pata_amd sata_nv floppy

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008089] CPU: 0 PID: 1614 Comm: firefox Tainted: P           OE  3.19.0-33-generic #38-Ubuntu

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008091] Hardware name: Kobian KN6100M/KN6100M, BIOS 6.00 PG 06/01/2007

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008094]  00000000 00000000 f4c39ebc c16ec002 f4c39f00 f4c39ef0 c106177b c1995ee0

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008099]  f4c39f1c 0000064e c1995f1c 0000012f c161ef9e 0000012f c161ef9e 00000000

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008104]  f4e9b000 fffffc83 f4c39f08 c10617e3 00000009 f4c39f00 c1995ee0 f4c39f1c

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008109] Call Trace:

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008117]  [<c16ec002>] dump_stack+0x41/0x52

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008122]  [<c106177b>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8b/0xc0

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008126]  [<c161ef9e>] ? dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008129]  [<c161ef9e>] ? dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008133]  [<c10617e3>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008136]  [<c161ef9e>] dev_watchdog+0x1fe/0x210

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008143]  [<c10bead0>] call_timer_fn+0x30/0xf0

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008148]  [<c109a52f>] ? __wake_up+0x3f/0x50

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008151]  [<c161eda0>] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x70/0x70

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008155]  [<c10c04ec>] run_timer_softirq+0x18c/0x2b0

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008158]  [<c161eda0>] ? dev_graft_qdisc+0x70/0x70

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008162]  [<c10655cc>] __do_softirq+0xec/0x230

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008166]  [<c10654e0>] ? cpu_callback+0x170/0x170

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008171]  [<c1013146>] do_softirq_own_stack+0x26/0x30

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008173]  <IRQ>  [<c1065875>] irq_exit+0x95/0xa0

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008180]  [<c16f30f8>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x38/0x50

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008183]  [<c16f283c>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x34/0x3c

Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008186] ---[ end trace b31c809dae7ef8dc ]---
Dec 29 15:37:24 PC040 kernel: [21333.008193] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 eth1: Got tx_timeout. irq status: 00000020

Dec 29 15:39:01 PC040 CRON[3351]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)
Dec 29 15:39:01 PC040 CRON[3350]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Created slice user-1000.slice.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting user-1000.slice.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Started Session 19 of user PC040.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting Session 19 of user PC040.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Timers.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Timers.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Sockets.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Sockets.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Paths.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Paths.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Basic System.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Basic System.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Reached target Default.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Startup finished in 117ms.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.

Dec 29 15:49:03 PC040 systemd[3477]: Starting Default.

Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 dbus[583]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' unit='console-kit-daemon.service'

Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 systemd[1]: Starting Console Manager...

Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 console-kit-daemon[3558]: missing action

Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 dbus[583]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit'

Dec 29 15:49:04 PC040 systemd[1]: Started Console Manager.
 && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `gksudo gedit /var/log/syslog`.